# New wwwroot folders and content deleted during build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Via VS2022 I have created a subfolder under wwwroot/js and dragged the js files required into that new folder.

During build, I can see that new folder and contents "disappear" from Solution Explorer and also the new folder is deleted from disk ......

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Probably the best way to track this down is to capture a binlog of the build and see what is deleting the files.  https://msbuildlog.com/ is a fantastic tool for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Silly Silly Me !**

I have been working with Blazor for so long (no javascript) - I had forgotten that during the build of this old website Gulp was clearing and repopulating wwwroot !

Simply adding the folder and content via Solution Explorer was completely wrong!

I feel such an idiot!